# d3.js How to give last and second last tick equally space

Tags: d3.js

I have drawn a chart with `time scale` on x-axis and `linear scale` on y-axis.
The problem is

1. y-axis last and second last ticks are not equally spaced as you can see in picture.
   [image]

**Update**
Same Case is with x-axis in [This link](http://jsfiddle.net/KWRxW/2221/)

Comment: You coul try `.outerTickSize(0)`

Comment: @CoolBlue but the top most `dot` value is `222`

Comment: Ok, have you tried nice-ing the axis scale? The other suggestion was to just remove the last tick mark...